# Eclipse IDE Java implicit casting

Tags: java, eclipse, casting, implicit-conversion

While updating my Eclipse IDE installation from Oxygen.3a (4.7.3) to Photon I have noticed that some of my code has broken despite compiling (and working) fine previously.

Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {

    class MyClass {

    }

    interface MyInterface {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stream<MyClass> myClassStream = new ArrayList<MyClass>().stream();
        Stream<MyInterface> myInterfaceStream = new ArrayList<MyInterface>().stream();

        Stream<MyInterface> concatenation = Stream.concat(

                // Tooltip for filter() displays the result type of Stream<MyClass>
                myClassStream.filter(element -> element instanceof MyInterface),

                // Tooltip displays type Stream<MyInterface>
                myInterfaceStream);
    }

}
```

In Photon, an error appears saying that `Stream.concat` returns `Stream<Object>`, not `Stream<MyInterface>`. In Oxygen, it did not (the return type was `Stream<MyInterface>`). It looks like something was implicitly casting the return type of `filter` to `Stream<? extends MyClass, MyInterface>` which then lead to `Stream.concat` returning the expected type. This was, of course, safe semantically as all the elements in the stream returned by `filter` did implement `MyInterface`.

Why did this code break? How could I get previous behavior?

Comment: The error reporting seems an improvement. Do `myClassStream.filter(...).(MyInterface.class::cast)`

Comment: Eclipse uses its own Java compiler so this is nothing to do with javac.

Comment: Well, in the actual code `MyClass` and `MyInterface` are not connected, either. However, there are several subclasses of `MyClass` that implement `MyInterface` and the filter attempts to sort them out.

Comment: @JoopEggen like this?
`myClassStream.filter(element -> element instanceof MyInterface).map(MyInterface.class::cast)`

Comment: Yes. Now the stream is of MyInterface, not MyClass which at runtime happens to be MyInterface objects.

Comment: While this is a way of making the code compile it adds another operation (=> overhead). Anyway, the question was "How can I enable previous behavior", not "How can I change existing code to fit the new behavior"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary:

- Your code is invalid.
- Oxygen's Java compiler incorrectly allows your code to compile.
- Photon's Java compiler correctly reports an error with your code.

`concat()` will return a Stream of a type which is the closest match for the types of the streams being concatenated. For example, if you `concat()` a `Stream<Int>` with a `Stream<Long>` then `concat()` will return a `Stream<Number>`.

And if you `concat()` two streams whose elements bear no relationship with each other, such as `Stream<String>` and `Stream<Long>`, then `concat()` will return a `Stream<Object>`. That is what happens in your code, since `MyClass` and `MyInterface` bear no relationship to each other, apart from having `Object` as a parent.

> It looks like something was implicitly casting the return type of
>   filter to Stream which then lead to
>   Stream.concat returning the expected type.

That explanation looks tempting since it appears to fit the facts, but what happens if the Predicate in your filter is changed to test for `Runnable` instead of `MyInterface`?

```
Stream<MyInterface> concatenation2 = Stream.concat(
    myClassStream.filter(element -> element instanceof Runnable),
    myInterfaceStream);
```

The code still compiles and the tooltip is unchanged, so the filtering is clearly not impacting the return type. Put another way, the first parameter to `concat()` will return a `Stream<MyClass>` regardless of what is done in `filter()`. The fact that your filter guaranteed that it would also only return `MyInterface` elements is not relevant, but it appeared to be significant because the type of the variable receiving the Stream from `concat()` was `Stream<MyInterface>`.

And what happens if the type of the variable receiving the Stream from `concat()` is changed from `MyInterface` to something absurd and meaningless such as `Deque<LocalDateTime>`?...

```
Stream<Deque<LocalDateTime>> concatenation3 = Stream.concat(
    myClassStream.filter(element -> element instanceof MyInterface),
    myInterfaceStream);
```

Two things are notable:

- Even though that code is obviously invalid, it still compiles on Oxygen (but not on Photon).
- The tooltip for `concat()` now shows its return type to be `Stream<Deque<LocalDateTime>>` which clearly makes no sense.

> Why did this code break? How could I get previous behavior?

Oxygen's compiler was allowing invalid variable definitions using `Stream.concat()`, and it seems that this was fixed in Photon. You shouldn't want that previous behavior since it was incorrect.